# javascript regular expression: how do I find date without year or date with year<2010

Tags: regex

I need to find date without year, or date with year<2010.
basically,

```
Feb 15
Feb 20
Feb 20, 2009
Feb 20, 1995
```

should be accepted

```
Feb 20, 2010
Feb 20, 2011
```

should be rejected

How do I do it?

Thanks,
Cheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`(Jan|Feb|Mar...Dec)\s\d{1,2},\s([1][0-9][0-9][0-9]|200[0-9])`

Note: Expand the month list with proepr names. I was too lazy to spell it all out.